# Can't I use a human-readable name for Vertex AI Endpoint?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

According to [the doc of Vertex AI Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.endpoints), each `Endpoint` has `displayName`, but it seems we cannot use that `displayName` to specify the `Endpoint` in [prediction](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.endpoints/predict) and we have to use human-unreadable URL like `https://{location}-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project}/locations/{location}/endpoints/{endpoint}` where `{endpoint}` is a sequence of digits.

Is there any good way to associate human-readable name to the endpoint and use it as the prediction URL?

Comment: Why do you want a human readable endpoint? It should be use by machine!

Comment: Hi @YukiHashimoto, Is your issue resolved? If not, can you please clarify on the above comment and your case?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for your response!
For example, when there are classification models version 1 and version 2, whose I/O types are exactly the same, the developer cannot notice that they are using wrong version as they expect by their code.